# Send File as a parameter to a REST Service, from a client?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

My Requirement is to send the file to the REST Service through one client. That service is going to process the file. I am using Jersey API for implementing this. But I have searched in many articles, there is no any information of **how to pass the file from client side** and **how the REST service will retrieve the file**... How to achieve this?

And I am not using the Servlets for Creating REST Service.

Comment: have you checked following link.? http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-jersey/

Comment: Thak you this link is useful. But in this link there is the information of how the service is getting the file and how it is uploading the file only framed. My requirement is How the client will call this fileUploadservice through send the File as a parameter.. that is file is in client side. It will send the file to the REST Service for some purpose.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are using Jersey on both the client and server side, here is some code that you can extend:

Server side:

```
@POST
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(final MimeMultipart file) {
    if (file == null)
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                .entity("Must supply a valid file").build();

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < file.getCount(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Body Part: " + file.getBodyPart(i));
        }
        return Response.ok("Done").build();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e)
                .build();
    }
}
```

The above code implements a resource method that accepts POST's of multipart (file) data. It also illustrates how you can iterate through all the individual body parts in the incoming (multipart) request.

Client:

```
final ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
final Client client = Client.create(config);

final WebResource resource = client.resource(ENDPOINT_URL);

final MimeMultipart request = new MimeMultipart();
request.addBodyPart(new MimeBodyPart(new FileInputStream(new File(
        fileName))));

final String response = resource
    .entity(request, "multipart/form-data")
    .accept("text/plain")
    .post(String.class);
```

The above code simply attaches a file to a multipart request, and fires the request off to the server. For both client and server side code there is a reliance on the Jersey and JavaMail libraries. If you are using Maven, these can be pulled down with ease, with the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency> <!-- only on server side -->
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency> <!-- only on client side -->
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.17</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.6</version>
</dependency>
```

*Adjust the dependency versions as required*

Comment: Thank you very much... This is what I really expected. Could you please tell the Maven Dependency of MimeMulitpart.. I am using the following dependency  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
   <version>1.17.1</version>
  </dependency>... Is that correct one?

Comment: @AnandMurugan - no, you do not need that dependency. I've added the core ones you need to my answer.

Comment: I have changed the code changes. But Now I am getting the exception of 404 Not found... But when I am hitting the URL it responds... But again the after executing the post the excpetion occurs... My service is running in the url http://myhost/agent.  I have added @Path("/upload") in Service Class, and also added @Path("transfer") in the uploadFile method.... Again want to know what is the Wrong with the code?

Comment: If you added a specific path to the resource method then you need to include it in the URL on your client side. So `http://myhost:9999/agent/upload/transfer` for example, as opposed to `http://myhost:9999/agent/upload`.

Comment: The code is working fine. But My requirement is just upload the files from client to server. So I don't want MIMEMulitpart type. Because I am not able get the exact file transfered. For Example If I am Sending a text file, while writing the file at server side, the text file created with "--null" content. And If I am transferring zip file, that writes at a bad format and not able to view the zip file. If we can pass the file using MIMEMultipart means how to get the exact file at server side code. Please help me to get this?

Comment: Hi Guys, not sure I guess a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001318/java-api-pass-in-url-file-location-on-client-machine?noredirect=1#comment57730882_35001318. Could you please share more details the examples how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Am I right by assuming, since its a MimeMultipart type, that I could not just send one, but multiple files or additional information maybe as String or whatever, on doing only one simple post, just by adding multiple MimeBodyParts containing the different files or whatever? for example like:

```
final MimeMultipart request = new MimeMultipart();
request.addBodyPart(new MimeBodyPart(new FileInputStream(new File(
    fileOne))), 0);
request.addBodyPart(new MimeBodyPart(new FileInputStream(new File(
    fileTwo))), 1);
```

etc.