# Best practice for file-based search in rest service

Tags: rest, http-method

I'm helping build a similarity search service for files. One way to search for something is with a GET request, by giving a file's URL, but I also need to allow clients to send the file directly. I have to following options:

1. Make the client send a GET request with a Payload; it seems this is not recommended -- [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)
2. Use something else than GET (maybe a PUT?) for file-based search. The problem is none of the other HTTP methods seems to suit this purpose.

What option would suit best here? I'm not an expert in this field, and I can't figure out what's the right thing to do in this situation.

Comment: i think this will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15262965/send-file-as-a-parameter-to-a-rest-service-from-a-client

Answer (score 1):

Here is the rule I have always followed with REST.

GET - only querying data and returning a data set.
POST - Creating data in the database
PUT - Modifying data
DELETE - Destroy data in the database.

If you are sending a payload for search params, you can do a GET and put those params (assuming they are name/value pairs) in the query string of the URI.

i.e. http://my.simsearch.com?param1=first&param2=second ...

If you are actually going to change the database then a POST or PUT is in order.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with you, but in my case the payload is a binary file, so I can't really put that in the URL. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Yep, I see that would be a problem in the URL. In that case my approach (maybe not a best practice) would be a PUT even though it doesn't necessarily fit into the REST paradigm it will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up sending the payload with a GET request. Even though it's not really recommended, hopefully no libraries will complain about this.